# How to prevent users from passing through objects in a webvr application?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

am new to webvr and need a little bit of help, so i built a virtual reality room, with little interior details, now i want a user to only move to specific points, for example say a user hovers over a window, than a the camera/view should jump to that window/point not necessary viewing outside just a little bit, this is to avoid users going through walls and objects. So how can one solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it right, thanks to JavaScript, so the camera now change position to that specific point you point on with cursor and than rotates.`function windowCameraChange(){var curt = document.getElementById("MainCamera");curt.setAttribute('camera', 'zoom', '1.450');curt.setAttribute('rotation','0 -90 0');}`